# Set NEHotspotConfiguration without system alert

Tags: ios

I have used NEHotspotConfiguration to programmatically join a WiFi network.

But when it joins a wifi network failed, it will show "Impossible to connect network "xxxxxxxx"" system alert.

Is it possible not showing "Impossible to connect network "xxxxxxxx"" system alert?

I want to show my own alert.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment i dont think you can do it because you dont even get an error in the closure - the error is nil , so you cant identify if success or error .
i have opened a bug about it to apple.